# Bug/Error con datepicker de angular material

Tags: angular, datepicker

tengo un error con un datepicker de angular material el cual no consigo solucionar. La cuestión es que necesito crear un datepicker que muestre la fecha con el formato DD/MM/YYYY. Desarrollé un DateAdapter customizado para que al seleccionar desde el modal, la fecha salga correcta, pero el problema viene cuando el usuario escribe la fecha a mano.

Cuando escribo la fecha, al perder el focus el datepicker, este me cambia el mes por el día. Ejemplo práctico:

Si yo escribo: 10/06/2020, cuando cambio de input en el formulario, el datepicker me cambia automaticamente la fecha a 06/10/2020. Depuré y no es que me estuviese cambiando la posición del mes y el día, si no que cuando meto la fecha a mano (10/06/2020), este lo interpreta como el 6 de Octubre de 2020.

Aquí está el código que tengo:

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="customDatePicker">
    <input
        aria-label="fechaMinDisposicion"
        placeholder="00/00/0000"
        matInput
        (keyup)="autoFormatDate($event)"
        [min]="minDate"
        formControlName="fechaMinDisposicion"
        [matDatepicker]="picker2"
         id="picker"/>
            <div matSuffix>
                <mat-icon
                    class="icon"
                    (click)="picker2.open()"
                    onKeyDown="picker2.open()">
                </mat-icon>
            </div>
    <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'screen',
  templateUrl: 'screen.component.html',
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'es-ES' },
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: CustomDateDirective },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: APP_DATE_FORMATS },
  ],
})
```

**CustomDateDirective**

```
 export class CustomDateDirective extends NativeDateAdapter{

  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat === 'input') {
      let day: string = date.getDate().toString();
      day = +day < 10 ? '0' + day : day;
      let month: string = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
      month = +month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      return `${day}/${month}/${year}`;
    }
    return date.toDateString();
  }

}

export const APP_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' },
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'input',
    monthYearLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'
    },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: 'numeric', month: 'long' },
  }
};
```

Comment: agrega tu CustomDateDirective

Comment: Ya está, @sioesi

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso tengo el Datepicker resuelto de la siguiente manera, tuve que implementar moment() (https://momentjs.com)

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input
    matInput
    [min]="minDate"
    [max]="maxDate"
    [matDatepicker]="dp3"
    placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento"
    class="browser-default"
    formControlName="born"
  />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp3"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp3 disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

y en el TS:

```
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
// @ts-ignore
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';
const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;
@Component({
  selector: '...'
  templateUrl: '...'
  styleUrls: ['...'
  providers: [
    
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },
  ],
})

export class ... implements OnInit {
  signUpFrom: FormGroup;
  minDate = new Date(1920, 1, 1);
  maxDate = new Date();
}

constructor(...){
 this.signUpFrom = new FormGroup({
     // Simplemente implemente moment() para restarle 12 años al valor inicial
     born: new FormControl(moment().subtract(12, 'y'), Validators.required),
   
     });
}
```